# Javascript string compression

Tags: javascript, string, compression

I'm trying to enter a javascript competition where the script has to be <= 1kb in size. Minifying and eval is allowed, so I've run it through google's closure compiler (which does slightly better than any others I've tried).

But I've found that if I convert the script to a string, and replace long words like 'function' and 'return' with single chars, I can reduce that even further. Then, by embedding the string in my script, performing the substitution to restore it, and then 'evaling' it, I can get the original behaviour.

So I was wondering if I could generalise this last method. Has anyone seen or written code to compress/decompress strings in this way? Feel like thinking about it?

**EDIT**
To make myslelf clear, I'm asking about compressing and decompressing strings in javascript - not minifying. E.g. how to find the most common patterns in a string, and how to write a tiny decompressor in javascript for strings where these occurences have been replaced with single chars.

Thanks.

Comment: Erm... maybe Dean Edward's /packer/?

Comment: http://compressorrater.thruhere.net/ - a helpful tool for comparing output from different minifiers or compression methods

Comment: None of the minifiers I've tried work as well as Google's (including packer), which I'm already using. The question is about compressing/decompressing strings - it just happens that my string is minified js.

Comment: maybe you've already read these, but here are two recent articles from A List Apart on how to write code that minifiers can compress more easily: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/better-javascript-minification/ http://www.alistapart.com/articles/javascript-minification-part-II/

Comment: @Jenni - cheers, I will read that. I actually got my script down to an acceptable size. But I'm still interested in this idea of compressing/decompressing inside the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you happen to be looking for http://www.iteral.com/jscrush/ ? I found it useful for the same competition  (I assume it is js1k).

Comment: Nope. That's another minifier. I'm looking to compress and decompress strings.

Comment: Apologies. That's exactly the sort of thing I was talking about.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered shortening your code by creating a shortcut for those JavaScript objects and methods that you use a lot in your code:

```
var d = document; var id = d.getElementById;
```

And then instead of writing

```
document.getElementById("foo")
```

You can write

```
id("foo");
```

Comment: Yep, done that already...but also, the closure compiler does it as part of it's optimisation as well.

Answer (score 0):

Tokenisation is the preferred method for compressing scripts as it works with the individual keywords and other names.

Comment: Most of this is done by the closure compiler - there are very few javascript keywords I'm using (function, return etc) but the closure compiler automatically makes all function names just 1 letter long, etc.